# Is there a Filepicker property to suppress unique auto generated key?

Tags: filepicker.io

We are using the pickAndStore API with S3 storage but do not want the extra unique key being added to filenames. Is there any way to turn this off? If not, would it be possible to add something to the api options?
This is causing us a lot of issues with multiple uploads to S3 of the same file from users potentially, but with different names, which eats up space. We want the new upload to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, it can be solved different ways:

1) Use the 'pick' API first, and then the 'store' API saving the filename using the 'path' option `{ path: 'myfilename.txt' }`
Remember you need to know the original filename from the 'pick' API in order to know the correct file extension.

The problem here is that the file will be saved twice, because the 'pick' call will save it automatically using an unique filename and then you use the 'store' call to save it your way.

2) If you don't care about the filename, but just want to know the correct S3 path, you can use the 'pickAndStore' API and then on the success function use the 'Stat' API to get the S3 file path, like this:

```
filepicker.pickAndStore({},
{
    location:"S3",
},
function(inkBlob) {
    var inkBlob = inkBlob[0];

    // Get uploaded file metadata
    filepicker.stat(inkBlob, function(metadata) {
        var s3Path = metadata.path;
    })
});
```

3) If you just want to know the correct S3 path (like in option 2), you can do like in option 1 but without using the 'store' call, only the 'pick' and then getting the file metadata.

Hope that helps and give you some directions.